# Как сменить содержимое (текст) дива через css?

Tags: css

Необходимо сменить содержимое div'a при наведении на него мыши. То есть, в нем изначально *первый текст*, а при наведении курсора должен появляться *второй текст*, **заменяя** собой первый.
Пытался сделать это через :after, но первый текст-то никуда не девается - просто добавляется второй поверх первого.

Comment: поместить внутрь два дива и менять их, не?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На дивах, как предложил qwabra:

```css
.text2 {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover .text1 {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover .text2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text1">text 1</div>
  <div class="text2">text 2</div>
</div>
```

На `before`

```js
.container:before {
  content: attr(data-unhover);
}
.container:hover:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" data-unhover="text 1" data-hover="text 2"></div>
```

Можно так же скрывать текст припомощи `font-size`, но нужно учитывать, что его можно будет выделить и скопировать

```css
.container:hover{
  font-size: 0;
}
.container:hover:before {
  font-size: 16px;
  content: attr(data-hover);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" data-hover="text 2">
  text 1
</div>
```